# Recv with TCP packet stream not sending ACK packet

Tags: c, linux

Hi I am writing a application that uses TCP to communicate with a HTTP server. However I am seeing that I don't respond with an ACK packet after each data packet is received.

Is this handled by the RECV routine?

Comment: Thank god you're not using Windows or I'd have just pointed you [here](http://grotto11.com/blog/slash.html). (it's an interesting read anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ACK packets are handled by the kernel.  In fact, the ACK will often be sent before your process returns from `recv()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the TCP level ACK, then yes, this is handled by the protocol stack.